# is there a function for reading a file txt with regular expresion

Tags: r

I have a txt file with the current format of rows

```
1\t[2,3,4,5,6,45]
2\t[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,43,5]
etc
```

I want read it as data.frame where the columns names are the numbers of rows and and the values are the numbers in brackets

```
1 2
2 4
3 4
5 4
```

Comment: The columns in the posted example have different lengths, how do you want the result to be in tabular form? Pad the shorter to the length of the longest?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to read with `readLines` and then do the transformation

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
str_extract_all(v1, "\\d+") %>% 
    map(`[`,-1) %>% 
    reduce(rowr::cbind.fill, fill = NA) %>%
    set_names(str_extract(v1, "\\d+"))
#     1  2
#1    2  4
#2    3  4
#3    4  4
#4    5  4
#5    6  4
#6   45  4
#7 <NA>  4
#8 <NA> 43
#9 <NA>  5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- readLines('file1.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with input as

```
x <- '
1\t[2,3,4,5,6,45]
2\t[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,43,5]
'
```

You can do

```
library(data.table)

x <- 
  fread(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', x))[, .(value = strsplit(V2, ',')[[1]]), V1]

dcast(x, rowid(V1) ~ V1)[, -'V1']

#       1  2
# 1:    2  4
# 2:    3  4
# 3:    4  4
# 4:    5  4
# 5:    6  4
# 6:   45  4
# 7: <NA>  4
# 8: <NA> 43
# 9: <NA>  5
```